# ImageMagick creates a small black border around a clipped image

Tags: image, imagemagick, clipping, image-clipping

For our website, we clip images based on a clipping path. Since this needs to be done daily, for a lot of images, we have set up a server on which we run ImageMagick.

I noticed that clipped images have a small black border around the product, where the original clipping path was.

When simulating clipping in Photoshop, there is no line visible. Any clues?

[Clipped with ImageMagic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gviVI.jpg)
[Clipped with Photoshop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR6ky.jpg)

For anyone interested, here is the original image:
https://media.hanos.nl/transfer/1adc93c00c808b346a13f4e03ac3b793f6be6c53c3d1493adfb072e09ef35426

Thank you in advance for helping me out!

Regards!

I'm not that well versed in ImageMagick, I'm curious what goes wrong.

Comment: I can only see 3 JPEGs and no clipping path?

Comment: What was your Imagemagick command?  What is your version of Imagemagick and platform/OS?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Imagemagick 6 has a little issue there. However it does not show in Imagemagick 7.  Nevertheless, you can anti-alias that away in Imagemagick 6. I am using Imagemagick 6.9.12-82 and 7.1.1-5

IM 6:

convert -quiet 61270542.jpg -alpha transparent -clip -alpha opaque -strip 61270542_clipped1_6.jpg

[image]

IM 7:

magick -quiet 61270542.jpg -alpha transparent -clip -alpha opaque -strip 61270542_clipped1_7.jpg

[image]

IM 6 antialiased:

identify -quiet -format "%[8BIM:1999,2998:#1]" 61270542.jpg |
convert -quiet 61270542.jpg +repage 
( - -negate -blur 0x5 -level 50x100% +channel ) 
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite 
61270542_clipped2_6.jpg

[image]

IM 7 anti-aliased:

magick identify -quiet -format "%[8BIM:1999,2998:#1]" 61270542.jpg |
magick -quiet 61270542.jpg +repage 
( - -channel rgb -negate -blur 0x5 -level 50x100% +channel ) 
-alpha off -compose copy_opacity -composite 
61270542_clipped2_7.jpg

[image]

Comment: Great! I'm going try this! Thanks for taking the time to answer this for me :) !

Comment: It has been confirmed to be a bug by Imagemagick developer.